# Twilio Phone Number Masking Using C#/mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I'm developing a cab service app where I provide drivers to call on clients cellphone. Here for some privacy reason I want is to mask my clients actual cellphone with the masked number so the privacy regarding personal number will be fulfilled.

Is there any twilio rest API through which i can accomplish my job regarding masking of cellphone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are interested, we have just released a preview of an API that performs number masking and maintains sessions between two users that are proxying through a number to each other. It's a declarative API specifically for these private communications between two users of your system.

The API is called [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/proxy). You can read about what [Twilio Proxy can do for your application in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/introducing-twilio-proxy.html).

You can [request access to Twilio Proxy with this form](https://www.twilio.com/proxy#request-access).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response!

I've almost done with this masking functionality.

If you just want to make the call, without any pre-logic, you can just make a request to call with the rest api: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls you can find examples in all the helper libraries.

You can just use the Twilio number as From value, or if you just want to forward the call, if you configure your Twilio number to use a \ verb, with a callerId attribute, it will forward any call that is incoming to this number with a masked number that you specified in the callerId: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial